# Available Movies as in example is not showing correct calculated field

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

the link http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/app/logic is followed and calculated field in

```
// add into Model_DVD_InStore
function dsql_count(){
    return $this
        ->dsql(null,false)
        ->field('count(*)')
        ->where('('.$this->calculate_is_rented().')!=','Y')
        ->where('dvd.movie_id=movie.id')
        ;
}
```

but this is an inner join and all dvds which are rented(do have entry in rented table) and returned are taken into account, but all dvds which are not yet rented are not  taken in account.. any solution ...

SOLVED ::

Answer (score 0):

With Agile Toolkit 4.2 (you need Git version or 4.2.1) you can use this:

```
$model->count();
```

It returns DSQL with applied conditions.